# Extract numbers from excel table

Tags: excel

I have a Excel table with 5 columns filled with numbers, for e.g.

```
A1   B1   C1   D1   E1
 4   12   23   37   41
 1    4   19   25   45
 4   20   25   31   44
```

I want to find the exact place (ROW,COLUMN) for each number.

In K1:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$3,H1)
```

where for e.g. H1=4 the result is 3

In (L1,M1,N1):

```
=SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$3=$H$1,ROW($A$1:$E$3)-ROW($A$1)+1),COLUMNS($L1:L1))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> and the result is L1=1,M1=2,N1=3

Now I want to find a formula which show me the COLUMN number. If I use in (L2,M2,N2)

```
=SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$3=$H$1,COLUMN($A$1:$E$3)-COLUMN($A$1)+1),COLUMNS($L2:L2))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> I have as result L2=1,M2=1,N2=2  which is not that I want. The order must be L2=1,M2=2,N2=1.

I have stuck with this. I use office 2007.

Comment: This question could use a lot of formatting and cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the results you got from the rows to get the columns maybe?

```
=MATCH($H$1,INDEX($A$1:$E$3,L1,0),0)
```

In L2, filled through to M2 gives you the results you are expecting. Note that this formula works only if the number you're looking for (here 4) appears only once in any given row.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem i have .Thank you Jerry